# Is there a way to remove the first occurence of a specific object type from a linked list in Java?

Tags: java, linked-list

I have a linked list of "gameObjects" called objects which contains instances of 2 subclasses, Beat, and Player. I want to remove the first instance of a beat in my linked list when a method is called. As it is the method removes a beat from a seperate linked list exclusively for beats, but since the beats are rendered using the second linked list, they do not disappear.

```
public static void hit(){
    //Method for player to hit the beat
    Beat currentObject = (Beat) Game.beatLinkedList.getFirst();
    int distanceToPlayer = currentObject.getX() - 200;
    if (distanceToPlayer <= 50){
        score +=100;
    }

    Game.beatLinkedList.removeFirst();
    System.out.println("Beat Linked List Length: " + Game.beatLinkedList.size());
    System.out.println("Score: " + score);
}
```

I've attempted to use `removeFirstOccurence`, but may have misinterpreted the meaning of this, and I know for sure the syntax is incorrect.

```
 Handler.object.removeFirstOccurrence(Beat.beat);
```

If anything else is needed for the question I'll add it when needed, but I think pretty much everything is there, sorry if not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `instanceof` keyword to check, for example the folowing code:

```java
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.ArrayList;


class GameObject {
    String name;

    public GameObject(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }
}

class Player extends GameObject {

    public Player(String name) {
        super(name);
    }
}

class Entity extends GameObject {

    public Entity(String name) {
        super(name);
    }
}

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        ArrayList<GameObject> list = new ArrayList<>();
        Player john = new Player("John");
        Entity doe = new Entity("Doe");
        Player jane = new Player("Jane");
        list.add(john);
        list.add(doe);
        list.add(jane);
        for (GameObject obj : list) {
            if (obj instanceof Player) {
                list.remove(obj);
                break;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Removes the first occurrence of a GameObject of type Player.